# BATCH SCRIPT : Delete lines that contains a specific characters in a file

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to delete all in a file all the lines that contains some values.
My file looks like the following:

```
"BLOT"  "GL.AC" "00350" "AMG"   "10502" "     " "                    "  "     " "     " "     " "     " "
"ACOD"  "BC.FF" "00350" "AMG"   "10502" "     " "                    "  "     " "     " "     " "     " "
"VARC"  "DF.RR" "00350" "AMG"   "10502" "     " "                    "  "     " "     " "     " "     " "
```

The idea is to delete all the lines that contains the string "BLOT" and "VARC"

The expected result is :

```
"ACOD"  "BC.FF" "00350" "AMG"   "10502" "     " "                    "  "     " "     " "     " "     " "
```

How can we delete those lines from the file using a batch script?

I've found this command but this doesn't delete lines

```
powershell -Command "(gc C:\TEST_AUTO.txt) -replace 'BLOT', 'XXXX' | Out-File myFile.txt"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts and ask a specific question. Just requesting code for free is clearly off-topic here! Hint: [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (both feature a `/V` option)...

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using the `FindStr` command as hinted by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl):

```bat
FindStr /V "^\"BLOT\" ^\"VARC\"" "C:\TEST_AUTO.txt">"myfile.txt"
```

Should you prefer a batch file `PowerShell` option:

```bat
PowerShell "GC 'C:\TEST_AUTO.txt'|?{$_ -NotMatch '^\"BLOT\"|^\"VARC\"'}|SC 'myfile.txt'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by usind the following:

FIND /V  "BLOT" C:\TEST_AUTO.txt >result.txt